# Find the global min of $\lfloor{(1/2)(\lfloor{N/p}\rfloor+3-\sqrt{(\lfloor{N/p}\rfloor+1)^2-4N})}\rfloor$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, maxima-minima, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Denote this function as ${a}_{l}$.  Here $p$ is prime but not necessary for the solution, just $p \ge 2$  is needed.  This solution is for fixed $p$ with $N$ allowed to vary.  Now a plot of this function shows that it oscillates until sufficiently large $N$.  That is $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} {a}_{l} = p+1$.  Also the square root term of ${a}_{l}$ establishes that $N\ge 2p(2p-1)$.

The problem is to show that the first occurrence of the global minimum of $p+1$ occurs at $N=p(p^2+p+1)$.  From this value of $N$ I can show that the global minimum is $p+1$.  I am interested in proving this case because this value of $N$ is a special value of the more general set of problems that I am working on.

I have tried taking the derivative of the ${a}_{l}$ with respect to $k$ with the floor functions dropped where $N\ge p*k$ or $N < (k+1)p$ from $k \le N/p < k+1$.  The problem is that when set to zero to find the max/min the variable $k$ vanishes.  I have also considered setting the first derivative to be less than zero and solving for $k$.  This results in $N=2p(2p-1)$ which is a local max/min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK take $N=p*w$ where $w=\lfloor{N/p}\rfloor$.  Set ${a}_{l} = p+1$. Then we have $$\lfloor{(1/2)(w+3-2(p+1)-\sqrt{(w+1)^2-4*p*w})}\rfloor$$  Call this function inside the floor function ${a}_{l}^{\prime}$.  Then we have the condition from the floor function $0\le {a}_{l}^{\prime} < 1$.  Solving for $w$ results in $w>p^2+p$ for $p\ge 2$.  Thus the first valid integer solution is $w = p^2+p+1$ or $N=p(p^2+p+1)$.  Substitution into the original problem indeed shows that $p+1$ is the global minimum with the first value at $N=p(p^2+p+1)$.

Once could also assume that $N = p*w+v$ where $v=N \text{ mod } p$ where $v \in \left\{{0,1,\cdots, p-1}\right\}$.  Then you get $w>p^2+p+v$ where the again the first solution occurs only when $v=0$.